# Nest.js raw bodyParser doesn't fire json function

Tags: nestjs, body-parser

I need to get raw body request for generating signature.
and when i found solution i faced with issue that json function not working
example below :

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';

@Injectable()
export class RawBodyMiddlewareMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  public use(req: IncomingMessage, res, next: () => any): any {
    json({ //json function not fired
      verify: (req, res, buffer) => {
        console.log(buffer);
        if (Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
          const rawBody = Buffer.from(buffer);
          req['parsedRawBody'] = rawBody;
        }
        return true;
      },
    })(req, res as any, next);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigation i understand that for some reason i need to mark bodyParser as false.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bodyParser: false,
  });
```

Comment: this will disable the default body parser. So you can use your customized one

Comment: Yes exactly what i needed. Because i need raw body for generate signature

Answer (score 1):

Just set `rawBody` to `true` and you can access it in `req.rawBody`

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
rawBody: true,
});
```